# Using if and else if functions with select inputs (converting results based on km and miles)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, select

I have been trying to build a race predictor calculator based off of Peter Riegel's formula for a couple of days now and have only managed to get it working when the original and future distances are set the same (See below).

However I would like for the user to be able to select kilometres or miles using 'select' and 'options' in the form for both the original and future distance. I have played around with else and else if statements in the script but have completely failed at this. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me crack this. (I have put the select and options in already so it is just the scripting that I need help with).

I am completely self taught so I apologise if the code below is a complete mess or incorrect. Thank you! James

```js
function predictorCalc()  //Predicting future race results
{

var d1 = document.predictor.d1.value;
var t1 = document.predictor.time1hr.value * 60 * 60 + document.predictor.time1min.value * 60 + document.predictor.time1sec.value * 1;
var deg = document.predictor.deg.value;
var d2 = document.predictor.d2.value; 
  
//NEED TO INPUT IF & ELSE IF STATEMENTS HERE TO MANIPULATE THE RESULT DEPENDING ON WHETHER THE DISTANCE SELECTED IN D1 or D2 is KM OR MILES//

t2 = t1 * (Math.pow((d2 / d1), deg)); //predicted time in seconds (Equation T2=T1*(D2/D1)1.06)

phr = Math.floor(t2/3600);        //total hrs
pmin = Math.floor((t2 - (phr*(3600)))/60);   //total mins
psec = Math.floor(t2 - (phr*(3600))-(pmin*60));  //total secs

document.predictor.time2hr.value = round(phr,0);
document.predictor.time2min.value = round(pmin,0);
document.predictor.time2sec.value = round(psec,0);

}


function round(x) {
  return Math.round(x*100)/100;
}
```

```html
<form name="predictor">

<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>D1 (Original distance)</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="d1" size="3">km</td>
  <td>
   <select size="1" name="d1units">
   <option selected="" value="k">Kilometers</option>
   <option value="m">Miles</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
   
 <tr>
  <td>T1 (original time)</td>
  <td><input name="time1hr" size="3" maxlength="2" type="text">hr</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="time1min" size="3">min</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="time1sec" size="3">sec</td>
 </tr>
   
 <tr>
  <td>D2 (Future distance competing in)</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="d2" size="3">km</td>
  <td>
          <select size="1" name="d2units">
    <option selected="" value="k">Kilometers</option>
    <option value="m">Miles</option>
    </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 
    <tr>
  <td>Performance Degradation</td>
  <td colspan="3"><input name="deg" size="2" maxlength="4" type="text" value="1.06">(6% or 1.06 as standard)</td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr>
  <td><input onclick="predictorCalc()" value="Calculate" type="button"></td>
 </tr>
   
 <tr>
  <td>T2 (Predicted future time)</td>
  <td><input name="time2hr" size="3" maxlength="2" type="text">hr</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="time2min" size="3">min</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="time2sec" size="3">sec</td>
 </tr>
  
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the java tag should not be included.

Comment: I'd recommend converting to one of the units already when reading out the inputs: `d1 = (document.predictor.d1units.value == 'km') ? document.predictor.d1.value : document.predictor.d1.value / 0.61;`

Answer (score 0):

```
function predictorCalc()  //Predicting future race results
{
  const kmPerMile=1.60934;
  var d1u = document.predictor.d1units;
  var d1units = d1u.options[d1u.selectedIndex].value;
  var d1 = d1units=='k'?document.predictor.d1.value:document.predictor.d1.value*kmPerMile;

  var d2u = document.predictor.d2units;
  var d2units = d2u.options[d2u.selectedIndex].value;
  var d2 = d2units=='k'?document.predictor.d2.value:document.predictor.d2.value*kmPerMile;

  var t1 = document.predictor.time1hr.value * 60 * 60 + document.predictor.time1min.value * 60 + document.predictor.time1sec.value * 1;
  var deg = document.predictor.deg.value;

  //NEED TO INPUT IF & ELSE IF STATEMENTS HERE TO MANIPULATE THE RESULT DEPENDING ON WHETHER THE DISTANCE SELECTED IN D1 or D2 is KM OR MILES//

  t2 = t1 * (Math.pow((d2 / d1), deg)); //predicted time in seconds (Equation T2=T1*(D2/D1)1.06)

  phr = Math.floor(t2/3600);                         //total hrs
  pmin = Math.floor((t2 - (phr*(3600)))/60);         //total mins
  psec = Math.floor(t2 - (phr*(3600))-(pmin*60));  //total secs

  document.predictor.time2hr.value = round(phr,0);
  document.predictor.time2min.value = round(pmin,0);
  document.predictor.time2sec.value = round(psec,0);

}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can change `var d1 = d1units=='k'?document.predictor.d1.value:document.predictor.d1.value*kmPerMile;
` to `var d1=document.predictor.d1.value; if (d1units=='m') { d1=document.predictor.d1.value*kmPerMile; }` and do the same for d2.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert! I hadn't considered using the const function and it works perfectly.